# Необходимо получить данные из двух таблиц и отсортировать по дате

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы.

Вывести 3 записи за последнюю неделю содержащих поле poster в порядке от самого популярного.

Первая таблица **anime_release**:

```
| id | poster       |
---------------------
| 1  | url_картинки |
| 2  | url_картинки |
| 3  | url_картинки |
```

Вторая таблица **anime_populate** содержащую id пользователя, id релиза и дату:

```
| id | anime_id | watcher_id | date       |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1    |      1     | 2020-03-26 |
| 2  |     1    |      2     | 2020-04-05 |
| 3  |     3    |      2     | 2020-04-05 |
| 4  |     1    |      2     | 2020-04-05 |
```

Comment: Не понятно по каким полям идет связь между таблицами: anime_id это id из anime_release? Какое из полей отображает число просмотров для сортировки по популярности?

Comment: Таблицы связаны при помощи полей anime_id и id из anime_release.

Comment: Никакое поле не отображает число просмотров, надо отсортировать при помощи count

Comment: Вообщем, надо найти одинаковые anime_id и по ним подсчитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверял код в PostgreSQL, доступа к MySQL не имею, так-что возможно код немного некорректен, но в целом все верно

```
SELECT count(p.anime_id) as wathed, p.date, r.poster
FROM anime_populate as p
INNER JOIN anime_release as r ON p.anime_id = r.id
GROUP BY p.date, r.poster
ORDER BY wathed DESC
LIMIT 3
```

- watcher_id ломает логику, по этому в выборку он не попал, в условиях его тоже не было
- Количество просмотров отображается как wathed
- За ТОП-3 отвечает 'LIMIT 3', в MySQL это будет 'TOP 3':
  `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tab`
- Для вывода записей за последнюю неделю нужно из сегодняшней даты, вычесть интервал в одну неделю. Это можно сделать с помощью функции TIMESTAMPDIFF() в MySQL. [Вероятно вы найдете помощь здесь](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/rabota-s-datoy-i-vremenem-v-mysql.html)

Comment: большое спасибо)